# How refresh part of page after editing asp mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I work with asp mvc I have a form and I edit some of this form, but after edition, change will not appear until I re-ran, I look how I can refresh this part edited of my form, this is my code :

controller :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditParticipant(GetParticipantModel model)
{
    model.FillDDL();
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        model.EditParticipant();
    }

    return RedirectToAction("_ParticipantDetail", model);
}
```

view :

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("EditParticipant", "GetParticipant",
    new AjaxOptions {
        HttpMethod="POST",
        OnComplete = "flipCard_1(jQuery(this), 0);" 
    }))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.Participants.StateCDR)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Participants.StartDate)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Participants.EndDate)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Participants.FinancialGroup)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Participants.Insurance)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Participants.Active)
    <div class="fsc-card-body-fixed">
        <div class="fsc-card-container-3">
            <div class="fsc-comp-infobox-2">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-2">
                        <label class="fsc-label-1">Code du Participant</label>
                        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Participants.ParticipantCode, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    </div>
...............................

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm fsc-btn-3" >
        <i class="fa fa-save"></i>
        <span>Enregistrer</span>
    </button>
}
```

Comment: Well for starters that would be [tag:asp.net] or possibly [tag:asp.net-mvc] not [tag:asp-classic] at any rate.

Comment: Please try to ensure when you copy and paste code that you reinstate the proper formatting so as to make it easier for readers to understand, thanks.